# Chromium based Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, updates, chromium, microsoft-edge

I searched to find about how can I get new Microsoft chromium based edge browser,
Is Chromium based Microsoft edge comes with an update of windows 10 9h1?

Comment: It hasn’t been released yet.

Comment: Chromium Edge (codename Anaheim) will be installed independently from 1905 (May 2019 Update aka 19H1).  A release date hasn’t been announced at this time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Chromium based Microsoft edge comes with an update of windows 10 9h1?

Windows 10 19H1 is going to be released in May.  Chromium Microsoft Edge isn’t going to be released in May.

Chromium Microsoft Edge will be installed independently from either 1905 (May 2019 Update/19H1) or 1910 (October 2019 Update/19H2) or any future Windows 10 feature update.

While Chromium Microsoft Edge has indeed been leaked and it can indeed be installed today, it’s not really functional, and it can only be downloaded from an unofficial source.  Since I don’t trust the source, I won’t be providing it, and encourage you to simply signup for Chromium Microsoft Edge testing through Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/).

You can download the Insider Preview build of Chromium Microsoft Edge [here](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/)

Comment: The reason it’s going to be renamed to May 2019 Update, is due to the fact, the final build will be in April instead of March.  The 1803 (April 2018 Update) initial final build was in March 2018 but wasn’t “released” until April 2018.  Of course last year was the exception not what typically will happen.  Any event, **May 2019 Update**, comes directly from [Microsoft](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/04/04/improving-the-windows-10-update-experience-with-control-quality-and-transparency/).  19-

Comment: Understood, good sir.  I wasn't questioning your usage of the "May 2019 Update" nomeclature, and I read the same Microsoft blog yesterday.  I was simply pointing out that the *version* number should still be 190**3** and not 190**5**, since the most recent Insider Preview releases I have seen retain the 1903 version while they increment the OS build number.

Comment: @Run5k - I have reason to believe 1903 will be changed to 1905 by next week and we will quickly see that same build in the Release Preview channel shortly after that.

Comment: "Reason to believe?"  Fair enough.

Comment: @Run5k - Its just a guy feeling.  Microsoft has not released a new build since they submitted that blog post that indicates the fact the April Update is now the May Update.  While they released a build on the same day as the post, that build, doesn’t reflect the new name either.  If I end up being wrong I will update my answer